# Excel 2011 MAC: TextChange or Change event for a worksheet Textbox

Tags: excel, events, textbox, vba

This is is Excel 2011, so no ActiveX controls. 
I have added a textbox to a worksheet (not a userform) and I need to be able to detect when the user enters text into the textbox and also be able to know what that text is as the user is typing it.

I have not been able to attach any events to this textbox.

```
Sub textmove()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, _
    1530.25, 520#).Name = "TextBox2"




    Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Textbox2").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "This is my textbox"

    Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Textbox2").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 45
        .StrikeThrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
  End Sub
```

But how do I attach an event to it?
I tried this in the worksheet code and I also tried it in the workbook code page:

```
Private Sub Textbox2_change()
    MsgBox ("event fired.")
End Sub
```

but that did not work.

Also, what events are there for a worksheet textbox?

I have not been able to find anything online.

What am I missing?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This made me curious as well. It looks like if you have to use a TextFrame you're quite limited when triggering events. One (ugly) way to simulate what you're trying to do:

Sheet1 module:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Test
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Test
End Sub
```

---

A new User module:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public shp As Shape
Private ws As Worksheet

Public Sub Test()

    Const SPACE_CHAR As String = " "

    Dim sz As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1
    If ws.Shapes.Count > 0 Then Set shp = ws.Shapes(1) Else makeTextFrame

    If Not shp Is Nothing Then
        With shp.TextFrame2.TextRange
            With .Characters
                sz = Len(.Text)
                If sz > 0 Then
                    If InStr(1, .Text, "x") > 0 Then
                        .Text = Replace(.Text, "x", vbNullString)
                    End If
                End If
                If Right(.Text, 1) = SPACE_CHAR Then .Text = Left(.Text, sz - 1)
                .Text = .Text & SPACE_CHAR
                sz = Len(.Text)
            End With
            If sz > 1 Then .Characters(sz).Select Else .Characters.Select
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub makeTextFrame()
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 250, 150)
    shp.OnAction = "'test'"
End Sub
```

---

A side effect is that a user will not be able to type anywhere else in the range of Sheet1 (can be an advantage if it's what you intend)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am getting an "argument not optional" error on With .Characters. even though the description of TextRange.Characters method says you can omit arguments. Should this work on Office 2011? What I am ultimately trying to do is to place the textbox on any cell the user selects and take and process the input. Is this possible? Or partially possible. I guess I could turn the placement of the textbox on and off depending on where the user clicks, right?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting the error; I tried it again and it works for me (maybe it works differently in Excel 2011 - I'm using 2010) but if parameters are optional for you too it should return all text... Related to your main task: are you sure you have to use a TextFrame for it? You can process every character entered or pasted in a cell, and it's much easier. If that's an option let me know and I can give you more details

Comment: That seems to me to be the only solution. I cannot process the user's input in a worksheet cell as it is being typed, as far as I know.  I want to use a listbox with possible choices and filter the choices as items are being typed to help ease the input. If I wait for the user to leave the cell, it will not be as useful.   I have also tried the verification lists but that comes with its own limitations.

Comment: The only way I could make your example work was to replace TextFrame2.TextRange with TextFrame.  With that, the only thing the textbox allows me to do is to click it. Then it runs the test function again. Like a button. I cannot type inside the textbox. If you have a file you can upload, I can try it on my mac to see if this is one of those Excel 2011 issues.  And once again thank you for your response and the code. This gives me hope that this may be doable. By the way, what were you trying to do with the "x" and the space character?

Comment: I looked for other ways to process user input as they type; there might be another way to capture key down\up events but it's a bit more complex (with API's) and it may not work in your case. I just realized that the answer doesn't provide the functionality you need either - it only triggers when the selection changes (not for every key pressed)

Comment: in your sample workbook, when you clicked on the textbox, would it allow you to type in it? From what I'm gathering, the onAction for the textbox is the handler for the click event, just like a command button. Am I wrong? The big problems with Excel 2011 are: no APIs (AFAIK) and you never know if you are doing something wrong is that just the way 2011 behaves!

Comment: when I click the textbox it allows me to type anything, but I did have a problem initially where I wasn't able to type. I fixed it by forcing the function to select the textbox: `If sz > 1 Then .Characters(sz).Select Else .Characters.Select`. The onAction is a handler for the click event, but only for the click event, not keydown. I combined it with the SelectionChange event, but that still triggers only when you select a different cell. I used the "x" to see if I can replace any characters typed by the user, and it does: "aaa bbb xxx ccc" becomes "aaa bbb ccc" when it triggers